# When and why to use AsRef<T> instead of &T

Tags: generics, rust, polymorphism, traits, parametric-polymorphism

`AsRef` documentation writes

> Used to do a cheap reference-to-reference conversion.

I understand `reference-to-reference` part what does it mean by `cheap`? I hope it has nothing to do with complexity theoretic (big Oh,. etc) "cheapness".

Example:

```rust
struct User {
  email: String, 
  age: u8,
}

impl AsRef<User> for User {
  fn as_ref(&self) -> &User {
     &self
  }
}

fn main() {
  let user = User { email: String::from("myemail@example.com"), age: 25 };
  let user_ref = &user;
  //...
}
```

What is the reason to implement `AsRef` for `User` if I can take a reference by simply `&user`?
What is the rule for implementing `AsRef`?

PS: I couldn't find anything answering these questions in other forums and docs.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

As you've noted, `impl AsRef<User> for User` seems a little pointless since you can just do `&user`. You could do `impl AsRef<String> for User` or `impl AsRef<u8> for User` as alternatives to `&user.email` and `&user.age` but those examples are probably misuses of the trait. What does it *mean* to be able to convert a `User` to an `&String`? Is the `&String` their email, their first name, their last name, their password? It doesn't make a lot of sense, and falls apart the moment a `User` has more than one `String` field.

Let's say we're starting to write an app and we only have `User`s with emails and ages. We'd model that in Rust like this:

```rust
struct User {
    email: String,
    age: u8,
}
```

Let's say some time passes and we write a bunch of functions and our app gets really popular and we decide we need to allow users to become moderators and moderators could have different moderation privileges. We could model that like this:

```rust
struct User {
    email: String,
    age: u8,
}

enum Privilege {
    // imagine different moderator privileges here
}

struct Moderator {
    user: User,
    privileges: Vec<Privilege>,
}
```

Now we *could* have just added the `privileges` vector directly into the `User` struct but since less than 1% of `User`s will be `Moderator`s it seems like a waste of memory to add a vector to every single `User`. The addition of the `Moderator` type causes us to write slightly awkward code though because all of our functions still take `User`s so we have to pass `&moderator.user` to them:

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct User {
    email: String,
    age: u8,
}

enum Privilege {
    // imagine different moderator privileges here
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct Moderator {
    user: User,
    privileges: Vec<Privilege>,
}

fn takes_user(user: &User) {}

fn main() {
    let user = User::default();
    let moderator = Moderator::default();
    
    takes_user(&user);
    takes_user(&moderator.user); // awkward
}
```

It would be really nice if we could just pass `&moderator` to any function expecting an `&User` because moderators are really just users with just a few added privileges. With `AsRef` we can! Here's how we'd implement that:

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct User {
    email: String,
    age: u8,
}

// obviously
impl AsRef<User> for User {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &User {
        self
    }
}

enum Privilege {
    // imagine different moderator privileges here
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct Moderator {
    user: User,
    privileges: Vec<Privilege>,
}

// since moderators are just regular users
impl AsRef<User> for Moderator {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &User {
        &self.user
    }
}

fn takes_user<U: AsRef<User>>(user: U) {}

fn main() {
    let user = User::default();
    let moderator = Moderator::default();
    
    takes_user(&user);
    takes_user(&moderator); // yay
}
```

Now we can pass a `&Moderator` to any function expecting a `&User` and it only required a small code refactor. Also, this pattern now scales to arbitrarily many user types, we can add `Admin`s and `PowerUser`s and `SubscribedUser`s and as long as we implement `AsRef<User>` for them they will work with all of our functions.

The reason why `&Moderator` to `&User` works out of the box without us having to write an explicit `impl AsRef<User> for &Moderator` is because of [this generic blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/convert/mod.rs.html#492-499) in the standard library:

```rust
impl<T: ?Sized, U: ?Sized> AsRef<U> for &T
where
    T: AsRef<U>,
{
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &U {
        <T as AsRef<U>>::as_ref(*self)
    }
}
```

Which basically just says if we have some `impl AsRef<U> for T` we also automatically get `impl AsRef<U> for &T` for all `T` for free.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that `AsRef<U>` is blanket `impl`emented for any `&T` where `T: AsRef<U>`, which is why you can call `takes_user(&user)` and don't have to pass `user` by value. This is a big part of what makes it useful as a general purpose (reference) conversion trait.

Comment: But I still don't understand, what it gives me. I see `&moderator` is better than `&moderator.user` but I could also send `&moderator` and take user as `user = moderator.user` inside `take_user` instead of writing ugly `<U: AsRef<User>>`. Clear and straightforward.

Comment: @HardFork How would you pass a `&Moderator` to `takes_user(user: &User)`? You can't, it's a compile error. You have to do `takes_user<U: AsRef<User>>(user: U)`. Also, it's okay to not like the trait and to not use it in your API designs. If there's no use-case for `AsRef` in your application then no one is forcing you to use it. The Rust standard library gets [decent mileage out of the trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html#implementors) by providing impls for `AsRef<Path>` and `AsRef<OsStr>` for the many various string types.

Comment: @pretzelhammer `take_user(&Moderator m) {...}`

Comment: @HardFork you changed the function signature so it no longer works for regular users, now passing a `&User` is a compile-time error.

Comment: @pretzelhammer Why do I need to pass User? Just pass Moderator. You can access the user if you have moderator.

Comment: @HardFork all Moderators are Users but not all Users are Moderators. In my answer I gave the example that less than 1% of Users would be Moderators. If you change the function signature to only accept Moderators you would be excluding 99% of your Users.

Comment: @pretzelhammer Ok, you mean you want to make the function generic, e.g., take_user must be able to accept anything that implements AsRef<User>.

Comment: @HardFork Yes, that's the primary use-case of the trait, for writing generic functions. If you write any Rust programs that work with the filesystem you'll notice that many standard library functions and methods are generic and take `<P: AsRef<Path>>` as an argument.

Comment: Seems like an adapter pattern to me.

Comment: @尤慕李 that is because it is. Rust's type system allows for _automatic_ adaptors via the `AsRef` trait. It is a form of [operator overloading](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/ops.html) that happens also perform the conversion at the same time.

Comment: Great answer @pretzelhammer! A question: for the blanket implementation in the std library which you had provided in your answer, why is the deferencing of `&T` in the fully qualified call to `as_ref` neccessary when the function signature of `as_ref` takes a `&T`? I.e. why do `<T as AsRef<U>::as_ref(*T)` and not `...::as_ref(T)`?

Answer (score 19):

> I hope it has nothing to do with complexity theoretic (big Oh,. etc) "cheapness".

It absolutely does. [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) is intended to cost essentially nothing.

> What is reason to implement AsRef for User if I can take a reference by simply &user?

There probably isn't one. `AsRef` is useful for generic code, especially (though not exclusively) for ergonomics.

For instance if [`std::fs::rename`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.rename.html) took an `&Path` you'd have to write:

```rust
fs::rename(Path::new("a.txt"), Path::new("b.txt"))?;
```

which is verbose and annoying.

However since it *does* take `AsRef<Path>` instead it works out of the box with strings, meaning you can just call:

```rust
fs::rename("a.txt", "b.txt")?;
```

which is perfectly straightforward and much more readable.

Comment: The `rename` would look even (slightly) worse, as you'd have to reference the paths: `fs::rename(&Path::new("a.txt"), &Path::new("b.txt"))?`

Comment: @user4815162352 nope it’s a bit unusual but `Path::new` actually returns an `&Path`. It could not do otherwise as `Path` is unsized, a bare `Path` is essentially the same thing as a bare `str`.

Comment: For the curious, `Path::new`'s [implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/path.rs.html#1999-2001)